# Quisiera encontar el error, es como si no realizara ninguna cuenta en la parte de "Calculando el empleado con mayor ventas por seccion"

Tags: c++

> En un comercio trabajan 20 vendedores, distribuidos en 4 secciones (bazar, accesorios, indumentaria, calzados). Se pide que se almacene la información de sus empleados.
>
> - Defina la estructura principal empleado se dese saber: nombre, legajo, sector, ventas diarias de cada día de la semana, ventas totales de esa semana (calculable).
>
> El comercio, tiene una política de premios semanales por ventas; para esto, al fin de cada semana determina cuales son los vendedores con mayores ventas por sector, y se guarda en Premiados.
>
> - Defina la estructura secundaria Premiados para almacenar por cada sector, legajo del empleado de mayor venta semanal y total vendido.
>
> Realice un programa que permita:
>
> 1. Cargar los datos de los empleados
> 2. Calcular el total de ventas semanales por vendedor.
> 3. Determinar por cada sector, el vendedor con mayores ventas, esta información debe ser almacenada en la segunda estructura.
> 4. Mostrar los nombres de los empleados premiados en una semana.
> 5. Listar todos los empleados y el total vendido.
>
> Analice detalladamente el ejercicio antes de abordar una solución.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

struct Empleado{
    char nombre[20];
    int legajo;
    char sector[20];
    int lunes;
    int martes;
    int miercoles;
    int jueves;
    int viernes;
    int vTotales;
}emp[20];

struct Premiados{
    char nombrePremiado[20];
    int legajo1;
}prem[20];

int main(){
    int mayorB=0, mayorA=0, mayorI=0, mayorC=0, posB=0, posA=0, posI=0, posC=0, totalVendido;
    //Ingreso de datos
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<"Nombre del empleado: ";
        cin.getline(emp[i].nombre,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Legajo N: ";
        cin>>emp[i].legajo;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<"Indique sector (bazar, accesorios, indumentaria, calzados): ";
        cin.getline(emp[i].sector,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Ventas del dia lunes: ";
        cin>>emp[i].lunes;
        cout<<"Ventas del dia martes: ";
        cin>>emp[i].martes;
        cout<<"Ventas del dia miercoles: ";
        cin>>emp[i].miercoles;
        cout<<"Ventas del dia jueves: ";
        cin>>emp[i].jueves;
        cout<<"Ventas del dia viernes: ";
        cin>>emp[i].viernes;
        cout<<"Ventas totales en la semana: ";
        emp[i].vTotales = emp[i].lunes+emp[i].martes+emp[i].miercoles+emp[i].jueves+emp[i].viernes;
        cout<<emp[i].vTotales<<endl;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    
    cout<<"\n...:PREMIOS SEMANALES:..."<<endl;
    
    //Calculando el empleado con mayor ventas por seccion
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        if(emp[i].sector=="bazar"){
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                if(emp[i].vTotales>mayorB){
                    mayorB = emp[i].vTotales;
                    posB++;
                }
            }
            strcpy(prem[posB].nombrePremiado,emp[posB].nombre);
            prem[posB].legajo1=emp[posB].legajo;
        }
        else if(emp[i].sector=="accesorios"){
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                if(emp[i].vTotales>mayorA){
                    mayorA = emp[i].vTotales;
                    posA++;
                }
            }
            strcpy(prem[posA].nombrePremiado,emp[posA].nombre);
            prem[posA].legajo1=emp[posA].legajo;
        }
        else if(emp[i].sector=="indumentaria"){
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                if(emp[i].vTotales>mayorI){
                    mayorI= emp[i].vTotales;
                    posI++;
                }
            }
            strcpy(prem[posI].nombrePremiado,emp[posI].nombre);
            prem[posI].legajo1=emp[posI].legajo;
        }
        else if(emp[i].sector=="calzados"){
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                if(emp[i].vTotales>mayorC){
                    mayorC = emp[i].vTotales;
                    posC++;
                }
            }
            strcpy(prem[posC].nombrePremiado,emp[posC].nombre);
            prem[posC].legajo1=emp[posC].legajo;
        }
    }
    
    
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"El empleado premiado en bazar es "<<prem[posB].nombrePremiado<<" legajo N "<<prem[posB].legajo1<<" con "<<mayorB<<endl;
    cout<<"El empleado premiado en accesorios es "<<prem[posA].nombrePremiado<<" legajo N "<<prem[posA].legajo1<<" con "<<mayorA<<endl;
    cout<<"El empleado premiado en indumentaria es "<<prem[posI].nombrePremiado<<" legajo N "<<prem[posI].legajo1<<" con "<<mayorI<<endl;
    cout<<"El empleado premiado en calzados es "<<prem[posC].nombrePremiado<<" legajo N "<<prem[posC].legajo1<<" con "<<mayorC<<endl;
    
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        totalVendido+=emp[i].vTotales;      
    }
    
    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        cout<<"Empleado "<<i+1<<". "<<emp[i].nombre<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Las ventas totales fueron "<<totalVendido<<endl;
    
    
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si anidas varios bucles `for` lo suyo es emplear distintas variables de control para los índices. Prueba a poner en el primer `for` una `i`, en em segundo una `j`… y así sucesivamente

Comment: Cambie todos los indices pero sigue haciendo lo mismo

Comment: Creo que el error está en que sumas 1 a las variables de posición como `posB++`. Me parece que ahí deberías almacenar el índice: `posB = j;`

Comment: @Fedex7501Probe y sigue igual, pero creo que ese tambien es un error. Me estoy volviendo loco jaja

Answer (score 0):

Martin seguramente ya lo resolviste, pero el error lo tienes en las comparaciones donde emp[i].sector=="accesorios" deberia ser

for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
empleados[i].vTotales>mayorB&&donde emp[i].sector=="accesorios"
y la posicion del mayor la deberias guardar en "i" y no usar un contador. luego de comparar y copiar el nombre y el legajo a la estructura Premiados imprimir el cartel que diga el vendedor con mas ventas por sector. Muchas Gracias, por tu aporte me sirvio mucho para guiarme. Saludos